# number_format strange issue with calculation

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5

I am working on a financial application. I store decimal to 20 like double(30,20). I am getting strange issue while calculation. I am using Laravel5.2. 
3 different result on PHP , Laravel, Excel

```
 Input1 = 280.95000000000000     
 Input2 = 278.76250000000000

//   Results Number_format to 14 
 $result = Input1 - Input2;
 PHP = 2.18750000000000 
 Laravel = 2.18750000000006 
 Excel = 2.18749999999994
```

These three different result effect the final % result. Can anybody know why this is different.

Answer (score 0):

Excel only has precision up to 15 figures (8 bits) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel. Laraval has 15 bits. php has approximately 14 bits http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Since many numbers cannot be exactly represented as decimals, errors do creep in. One simple solution is to move the decimal point so that there are only integers.

```
Input1 = 280.9500000000*10000 -> 2809500
Input2 = 278.7625000000*10000 -> 2787625
result = (Input1-Input2)/10000 -> 21.875
```

Comment: what's about mysql double is it can store double (30,20)

Comment: You can have 0.1 to 100 decimal places (in binary) and it will still be inaccurate. http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/ In pure math, every decimal has an equivalent bicimal. In floating-point math, this is just not true.